# ElasticSearch | SimpleQueryString | FieldBoosting is not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

**Mapping:**

```
   {
  "s_q_s" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "f1" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "f2" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "f3" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Documents:**

```
    {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yArwuXQBrACLjhbhLKPa",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "major",
          "f2" : "general",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yQrwuXQBrACLjhbhT6OJ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ygrxuXQBrACLjhbhi6Op",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major major major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ywrxuXQBrACLjhbhuKME",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Query:**

```
GET s_q_s/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "major",
      "fields": ["f1","f2^2"] //<===== f2 is twice important that f1
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yArwuXQBrACLjhbhLKPa",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "major",
          "f2" : "general",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "yQrwuXQBrACLjhbhT6OJ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ygrxuXQBrACLjhbhi6Op",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major major major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "s_q_s",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "ywrxuXQBrACLjhbhuKME",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "f1" : "general",
          "f2" : "major major",
          "f3" : "ram"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Docs Excerpt:**

> You also can boost relevance scores for matches to particular fields using a caret (^) notation

**Question:**

Why the document with "major" in f1 in coming on the top rather than once with "major" in  f2, when i have defined that f2 is twice as important as f1 while querying ?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to documentation on [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html), individual fields can be boosted automatically — count more towards
> the relevance score — at query time, with the boost parameter

**Search Query without boost:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "f1",
                "f2"
            ],
            "query": "major"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2039728,  <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "f1": "major",
          "f2": "general",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.48608798,   <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "f1": "general",
          "f2": "major major major",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      }
]
```

**Search Query with boost `2`:**

Matches on the `f2` field will have twice the weight as those on the `f1` field, but still, the score of `f1` field is more than that of `f2`

You can see in the previous search query, the score of matching `f2` field was `0.48608798`, now since the boost of `2` is applied, the score has become `0.48608798 * 2 = 0.97217596`.

But then also the score of `f2` field is less than that of `f1` field as `0.97217596` < `1.2039728`.

```
{
    "query": {
        "simple_query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "f1",
                "f2^2"
            ],
            "query": "major"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2039728,   <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "f1": "major",
          "f2": "general",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.97217596,   <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "f1": "general",
          "f2": "major major major",  
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      }
]
```

**Search Query:**

Now boosting the `f2` field value with parameter `3`, you can see significant changes in the score. Therefore, now the result is coming accurately according to your requirement.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "fields": [
                "f1",
                "f2^3"
            ],
            "query": "major"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.4582639,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "general",
          "f2": "major major major",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 1.4144535,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "general",
          "f2": "major major",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.2975104,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "general",
          "f2": "major",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "stof_64023501",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.2039728,
        "_source": {
          "f1": "major",
          "f2": "general",
          "f3": "ram"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Oh yes.. thanks for the answer.. I somehow missed checking the score without applying weights.

Comment: @SahilGupta thank u for accepting my answer, it would be great if you can upvote it as well :)